# convert 64 bit decimal to binary

Tags: c, ieee-754

I want to convert double num to binary, but mantissa does not work and I dunno why, here is the code...
please do not use other libs (only stdio)

```
 void printBinary(int n, int i)
{
    int k;
    for (k = i - 1; k >= 0; k--) {

        if ((n >> k) & 1)
            printf("1");
        else
            printf("0");
    }
}
typedef union {
    double f;
    struct
    {
        unsigned long long mantissa : 52;
        unsigned long long exponent : 11;
        unsigned long long sign : 1;

    } raw;
} myDouble;
void printIEEE(myDouble var)
{
    printf("%d |", var.raw.sign);
    printBinary(var.raw.exponent, 11);
    printf(" | ");
    printBinary(var.raw.mantissa, 52);
    printf("\n");
}
```

then I do in main

```
myDouble var;
var.f = -8.34;
printf("IEEE 754 representation of %f is : \n",
        var.f);
    printIEEE(var);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add your output and expected output.

Comment: "does not work" is not a useful problem description.

Comment: Did you check that th struct has the size you expect and that the bitfields are located where you think they are? You might check proper bit positions with some `uint64_t` instead of  `double`

Comment: Also please show complete `main` function instead of incomplete fragment.

Comment: I forgot to pass the parameter, I didn't have a warning in that line

Comment: I tested before on a different value that gave zeros in the mantissa. I tried  with value -2.25 and I receive 1 |10000000000 | 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your binary print function is

```
void printBinary(int n, int i)
```

but you are passing `unsigned long long` values. Please change the function to

```
void printBinary(unsigned long long n, int i)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help